# get rid of whitespace when using in Verb in tabu*

Tags: tabu, fancyvrb

Is there any way, to get rid of the extra whitespace between the command and the curly braces when using a Verb in a tabu*?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb, tabu}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu*}{XX}
\Verb_\vspace{}_&some Text
\end{tabu*}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use verb (which is always going to have some issues when used in such places:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb, tabu}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu*}{XX}
\texttt{\string\vspace\{\}}&some Text
\end{tabu*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `verbatimbox` instead of `fancyvrb`.  In essence, the `\verb` is done outside of the `tabu` environment and placed inside a LaTeX box.  Then, once inside the environment, the box is typeset, so that use of `\verb` is avoided inside the `tabu` environment even though the typeset box gives the impression that `\verb` in inside.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}\vspace{}\end{verbbox}
\begin{tabu*}{XX}
\theverbbox&some Text
\end{tabu*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But David Carlisle ones suits better for me because I allready use `fancyvrb` and `minted` packages for verb. If not neccesary I dont want to use a third one. Nonetheless I'll keep `verbatimbox` in mind.